# Moment time is returning UTC time instead of local time

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

Currently I am working on a project to create excel report when user clicks on Download Report Button from Application. Everything is working fine except the file name which is getting downloaded.

The problem is when we check from US (CST Time with Daylight Savings), suppose if user downloads the report at Nov 26, 9:00 pm, the file name is getting as Nov 27, 2020. We are using moment in node.js application for getting the time.

```
const date = moment().format('LL');
```

Can somebody knows where I am missing. If I am correct, the moment() function will return local time instead of UTC time. But seems to be getting UTC time instead of local time.

Do we need to use moment().local() instead?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you check a timezone on a server where your backend app is running?

Comment: @Anatoly Code is in aws serverless. It's us-west2

Comment: What does `moment.locale()` return?

Comment: did u try moment [time-zones](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

Comment: @Anatoly its retuning en.

Comment: @Miky Nope inorder to get local time we need to get timezone from front end application?

Comment: Yes, now you're getting with a server time zone

Comment: @Anatoly so how can we fix this? Any idea on how to get local time zone.

Comment: you can send it as timezone offset in URL like this: somesite.com/api/report?offset=-180

Comment: @Anatoly okay can we then convert to local time without moment? Can you add the same in Answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should pass a user timezone offset in URL:

```
// -300 - (CST with daylight savings)
https://somesite.com/api/report?offset=-300
```

And on a backend to change an offset with moment.js like this:

```
// old versions of a moment.js
const date = moment().zone(offset).format('LL')
// new versions of a moment.js
const date = moment().utcOffset(offset).format('LL')
```